# NGINX open index.php even when use this url http://serverip/htdocs/

Tags: nginx

what is proper NGINX configuration to display index (for example index.php) even not type the full url , for example

http://serverip/htdocs/ and not http://serverip/htdocs/index ?

when i type http://serverip/htdocs/ i got 404

Comment: server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.php login.php;

        server_name _;

        location /frontend/htdocs/ {
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }


        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }
}

Comment: whit this config still no luck